# Can't match RewriteRule

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to do a very simple URL rewrite but my RewriteRule is not working.

I want this URL: http://myweb.com:8080/MySite/bla?bla

To become this: http://myweb.com:8080/MySite/index.php

My .htaccess file content is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule bla\?bla index.php
```

It is located in "MySite" folder. I can do other url-rewriting rules with success but I got stuck whenever I need to write a rule with question mark inside.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you putting the .htaccess file ? In MySite ?

Comment: As I already wrote in the question, yes in "MySite".

Comment: Ok. It's only logical that it doesn't match. What comes after `?` will become a GET variable. So your URl becomes `/MySite/bla` with a GET variable, which key is `bla`. Try to use `RewriteRule bla index.php`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` rewrite condition for this.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^bla$
RewriteRule ^/?bla$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Please, note that the `?` in the rewrite rule is not there to match against the `?` in the query string. That part is handled completely by `%{QUERY_STRING}`. The `[NC]` just makes the rule case-insensitive and `[L]` marks the rule as last.